# Как получить значение температуры видеокарты AMD в Python под Windows 10

Tags: python, gpu

Видеокарта AMD 6900XT, библиотека psutil не работает в Windows, gputil работает только с видеокартами Nvidia. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Open Hardware Monitor
Попробуйте это:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62936850/16577058

Comment: Спасибо, Павел, вы очень мне помогли! Единственное, что Python.NET 2.5.2 поддерживает Python версии не старше 3.8 (у меня стоит 3.10), поэтому пришлось создать виртуальную среду с данной версией Python.

Comment: Почему не использовать WMI?